# Quantum Grassmannians?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, grassmannians

In noncommutative algebraic geometry a commonly studied family of objects are  quantum projective spaces. Theses are certain deformations of the homogeneous coordinate ring of $\mathbb{CP}^n$. For example, see this [mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109347/point-modules-of-quantum-projective-space-mathbbpn). The obvious question I would like to ask is whether or not people consider a Grassmannian generalisation of such objects, and if so, what are some well-known references.

Comment: For a notion of a noncommutative Grassmannian, see the MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168993/universal-unital-c-algebra-generated-by-the-relations-of-an-n-by-n-projection

Comment: These discussions are all valid approaches to quantum grassmannians. But more similar to the quantum projective space is the notion of quantum flag varieties--I.e. Those coming from quantum groups--which I worked out the gluing for the affine patches in my thesis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently, [quantum grassmannians](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quantum_Grassmannian) come in many variations --- this may be what you are looking for:

[Graded quantum cluster algebras and an application to quantum Grassmannians](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2133), Grabowksi & Launois, 2010.

> Among those who study quantized coordinate rings, it is widely
>   acknowledged that Grassmannians have a special place. The intricate
>   geometric structures associated to Grassmannians, due in part to their
>   Lie-theoretic origins, give a rich structure of their quantized
>   coordinate rings, the *quantum Grassmannians*.

Comment: Thanks for the links Carlo! However, the second is not a noncommutative space, but something coming from quantum cohomology/string theory. The others are quantized coordinate algebras, not quantized homogeneous coordinate rings, as in the linked question.

Comment: There are also various papers by Stokman and Letzter

Answer (score 2):

There is a deformation quantization approach to the quantization of the Grassmannians taking their Kähler symplectic form as the starting point. You can find this in the preprint by Schirmer arXiv:q-alg/9709021 from the nineties. He wrote a PhD on that. There are many earlier works on the quantization of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ in the same spirit, starting perhaps with works of Moreno and collaborators in the early eighties. You find many references in Schirmer's preprint.

However, this is not directly a $C^*$-algebraic approach, if you are interested in things like that. Nevertheless, the (a priori formal) star product is algebraic on many nice functions (the representative functions).